# Can an attributive adjective come before pronouns?

Tags: adjectives, pronouns

For example, the attributive adjective *only* and pronoun *one*: can we say "there is only one"?

Comment: Are you including possessive pronouns?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your question doesn't seem to be on-topic. Please edit your question to include full context and example usages. You already received 2 close-votes.

Answer (score 4):

Pronouns do not normally allow internal pre-head dependents. *"Extravagant he bought a new car", for example, is completely impossible. I say 'normally' because there is one minor exception, the use of a few adjectives such as "lucky", "poor", "silly" with the core personal pronouns:

"**Lucky you**! No one noticed you had gone home early".

"They decided it would have to be done by **poor old me**."

There is a restriction, though: the pronoun must be in accusative or plain case (compare "poor old me" and *"poor old I")

Comment: thanks a bunch
sorry if couldn't explain more, because my English is not good 
but for example the attributive adjective "only" and pronoun "one"

Comment: can we say  "there is only one" ?

Comment: The song [*Inflatable you* by Tim Minchin](http://www.timminchin.com/2005/10/11/inflatable-you-lyrics/) has about fifteen or so examples of *you* with internal pre-head dependents using a very wide range of adjectives indeed. None of these vocative uses seems ungrammatical ... Probably best [listened to](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e6raVzrbqrM) rather than read ...

Comment: I just deleted two *'s. Please take a look. +1)

Comment: Rathony. The NPs *"Extravagant he" and *"Poor old I" (and others like *"Silly I!") are all clearly ungrammatical. I have undone your edit.

Comment: @Rathony: the * before the phrases is a convention for indicating that they are not grammatical. More info here: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2392/what-does-this-mean

Comment: @sumelic I know the usage. I was confused as BilIJ used "***poor old me***" without "*".

Comment: Thanks for your help but my question was about the attributive-only adjectives like "ruined" and pronoun like " one" for example we can say " a ruined castle" but i don't know if we can say " a ruined one "

Comment: haha. I understand, but the "one" in "a ruined one" (and "There is only one") is a common noun, not a pronoun. Which is why I only gave you examples with genuine pronouns. "One" is a pronoun in "One can't be too careful", but it's not one of the core members.